# Xilinx ISE ROM memory error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, rom

Ive defined for my project a Single-Port ROM, using the Block Memory Generator of ISE tools.
It appears as part of my project, but i'm having a error message implementing my top module. wich says:

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:709 - "C:/Users/Neander/Project/SinHandler.vhd" Line 56. memory_sin is not an entity name
```

Here's my .vhd:

```
memory: entity work.memory_sin -- BRAM with the sin values 
    port map(
    clka => clk,
    addra => mem_addr,
    douta => dout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is `memory_sin` defined?

It looks like you haven't got the file with it in in your projects (or maybe it's too far down the list, so hasn't been analysed by the time you've tried to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Martins point, The VHDX 4KB size logical area size helps improve performance compared to VHD files.
Check for any typos or missing components in the entity declaration.